# Visual Studio 2019 debugging wcf service very slow to load WcfSvcHost.exe in windows tray icon

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2019

I have an old solution has 11 WCF projects referenced in many windows forms projects.

When I hit F5 to start debugging, visual studio 2019 loads each WCF in WcfSvcHost in windows tray icon then it starts debugging. That is normal.

The problem is that it takes around one second to load each WCF service in the windows tray icons.

I wish to find how it becomes like previous versions of visual studio to load all WCF projects in only 2 seconds.

Comment: As far as I know, during debug process in VS, the debugger uses IIS express to load the WCF service. So it should not make big difference when debugging the same project in two VS versions. Do you debug the project in same machine? And what's the old vs version you use?

Comment: I do not see IIS Express loaded in the windows tray icon. I see WcfSvcHost.exe only.
- This was a clean windows install + vs 2019 community.
- I think but not sure that after a VS update, the load of each wcf became slower. I am not sure that the update is the main reason.
I wish to know what exactly affects the performance of loading WcfSvcHost.exe while debugging in VS.
I tried basics such us disable firewall, disable antivirus, create a new solution with only one wcf project as a server and another one as client referencing that wcf and calls only one contract and still slower.

Comment: Hi Tarek, have you tried to use **Start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)**, would it be more faster than loading the each WCF in debug mode. I mean if we just start but not debugging, the WCF service host will also use the WcfSvcHost.exe to load wcf, it helps locate the cause of the issue by determining if this issue is related to vs debugger or other things.

Comment: Start without debugging = 4 seconds, Start with debugging = 00:04:56.86, each wcf load in tray icon = 3 to 4 seconds, this solution has 33 wcf + 52 assemblies.

Comment: I remember that in VS 2015 those commands fixes that problem: ['code'] (netsh http delete urlacl http://+:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/)
['code'] (netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ user=INTERACTIVE delegate=yes listen=yes) now it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

After two day search for the root cause of this problem, now I am sure that Windows 10 1903 + KB4506991 will slow Visual Studio wcfTestClient.

I uninstalled the KB4506991 update and it is debugging my solution very fast as before.

I reinstalled the KB4506991 update and it returned slower again.

I uninstalled it and it becomes faster.

The best thing for me is to uninstall it until I get more information about that.

[This is a link for KB4506691](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4506991/july-9-2019-kb4506991-cumulative-update-for-net-framework-3-5-and-4-8)